# Como mostrar o ''objectHTMLDivElement"?

Tags: javascript, html5

Tentei mostrar uns valores que estão em uma div com um `document.getElementById("valor")`. Utilizei comando `alert();` para mostra oque traria e mostrou na janela `objectHTMLDivElement` como posso mostrar isso ?

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var x = document.getElementById("valor");
    var text = "";
    alert(x);

    var data = [text];
    var tooltips = [];

    var line = new RGraph.Line({
        id: 'cvs',
        data: data,
        options: {
            tooltips: {
                self: tooltips,
                highlight: false
            },
            colors: ['#058DC7'],
            filled: true,
            fillstyle: 'rgba(229,243,249,0.5)',
            tickmarks: 'filledcircle',
            background: {
                grid: {
                    vlines: false,
                    border: false,
                    autofit: {
                        numhlines: 10
                    }
                }
            },
            shadow: false,
            linewidth: 3,
            gutter: {
                left: 50,
                right: 20
            },
            numxticks: 0,
            ylabels: {
                count: 5
            },
            axis: {
                color: '#aaa'
            },
            text: {
                color: '#aaa'
            },
            labels: ['21/01', '22/01', '23/01', '24/01', '25/01']
        }
    })

    RGraph.ISOLD ? line.draw() : line.trace2();

})
```

HTML

```
<html>

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="demos.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <script src="/sistema/jquery/plugins/RGraph/libraries/RGraph.common.core.js"></script>
        <script src="/sistema/jquery/plugins/RGraph/libraries/RGraph.common.dynamic.js"></script>
        <script src="/sistema/jquery/plugins/RGraph/libraries/RGraph.common.tooltips.js"></script>
        <script src="/sistema/jquery/plugins/RGraph/libraries/RGraph.line.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.load("jquery", "1.3.2", {
                uncompressed: true
            });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="json.class.js"></script>
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="../excanvas/excanvas.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <p style="margin-left:50em;">
            <title>Cotação USD x BRL</title>
        </p>
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
        <meta name="Descrição" content="Cotação do Dolar de Acordo com o Real" />
    </head>

    <body>
         <h2></h2>

        <canvas id="cvs" width="900" height="300">[No canvas support]</canvas>
        <div id="valor"></div>
        <div id="label"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Quando usas `document.getElementById("valor")` isso vai dar-te uma referência ao Objeto DOM com a id `valor`. Esse objeto tem várias propriedades, uma delas que acho que é a que queres é o [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

Assim se usares `document.getElementById("valor").innerHTML` isso vai dar-te o HTML que está dentro dessa div.

Usando o teu código seria:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var data = document.getElementById("valor").innerHTML;
    alert(data); // dá uma string com o que tiveres dentro dessa div
});
```

Se quiseres o conteúdo da div sem ter tags de HTML podes usar o [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).

Comment: Alterei no arquivo mais agora o "alert();" vem vazia

Comment: @nardo_bruxo no exemplo que colocaste na pergunta a div está vazia... Tens algum conteudo na DIV?

Comment: Estão sendo eviados numeros de um arquivo JSON do servidor para a página html que contem a div. No navegador aparece assim ex: "2.51,2.56,2.87,2.89,2.94", mas quando mando mostrar vem vazio pq ?

Comment: @nardo_bruxo coloca na pergunta todo o código que tens e ai posso explicar melhor. Provavelmente a div ainda está vazia no momento do alert mas é preenchida logo de seguida. Explica também a funcionalidade da página para percebermos melhor e assim podermos ajudar-te melhor também.

Comment: A página faz um gráfico. Quando os valores da Div "valor" forem colocados na variavel "data" o gráfico vai se formar (OBS: Este gráfico está em um servidor.). Já tentei usar xmlhttp, Jquery para tentar botar os valores na variavel mais não consigo podes me ajudar por favor !.

Comment: @nardo_bruxo dizes em cima que "Estão sendo eviados numeros de um arquivo JSON do servidor para a página html que contem a div"... onde? não vejo esse código na tua pergunta? via AJAX? ou via PHP?

Comment: é via AJAX. Como posso pegar os dados com jQuery.getJSON() ou com qualquer outro geito 
?